# How to display user name instead of id (foreign key) in laravel & vue.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display the user name instead supervisor_id in the table list in Vue.js. this is one to many relationship. supervisor_id is foreign key from user table.

/// this is view in vue.js. I want to to change work.supervisor_id into something like work.user.name, but it do not work.

```
<tr v-for="(work,index) in works.data" :key="work.work_id">
                <td>{{index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{work.work_name}}</td>
                <td>{{work.supervisor_id}}</td>  
                <td>{{work.payment}}</td>
                <td>{{work.created_at | myDate}}</td>
                <td>{{work.end_date}}</td>
                <td>{{work.worker_id}}</td> 
                <td>
```

/// this is my script in vue.js

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return{
      editmode: false,
      works:{},
      index:1,
      users:{},
      form: new Form({
        work_id:'',
        work_name:'',
        description:'',
        payment:'',
        location:'',
        end_date:'',
        worker_id:'',
        application_status:'New',
        supervisor_id:'',
                   })
    }
  },

  methods:{

    getResults(page = 1) {
            axios.get('api/work?page=' + page)
              .then(response => {
                this.works = response.data;
      });
    },


    loadWork(){
      if(this.$gate.isClerk()){
       // axios.get('api/work').then(({data})=>(this.works = data));
       axios.get('api/work').then(response => (this.works = response.data));
      }
    },
```

/// this is my work controller

```
public function index()
{
    return Work::latest()->paginate(10);
}
```

[the data in the vue.js devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi4li.jpg)

Comment: Hi Mohd, please reduce your question at the maximum around your problem, and be clear with indented code etc. Thanks you

Comment: i have updated my question. Hope you can help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this to work, it would require the a relationship on the `Work` model which returns the `supervisor` record which you require.

This will allow you to get the `supervisor`'s (or `user`'s depending on the relationship) name.

Work Model (`app\Work.php`):

```
public function supervisor()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'supervisor_id');
}
```

Now in your controller, you can use the `->with()` eloquent method to eager load a relation:

```
public function index()
{
    return Work::with('supervisor')->latest()->paginate(10);
}
```

You should now be able to access the supervisor name within vue using:

```
{{ work.supervisor.name }}
```

I hope this helps.